# Cannot set Keycloak user attribute in EventListenerProvider

Tags: java, keycloak, transactionmanager, keycloak-spi

When using "onEvent" method in my custom EventListenerProvider, I need to set attribute "isAfterFirstLogin" to "true", but only get exception: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access delegate without a transaction**

I was trying to use
**KeycloakTransactionManager transactionManager = session.getTransactionManager();**
**transactionManager.begin();**
**transactionManager.commit();**
and
**KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction**

but didn't succeed (the same exception). Fetching the attributes map, and manually putting the attribute won't help, as the change won't be persisted and will be reset after user's session is closed.

Is there any workaround for the issue or any other way how it can be handled?

Keycloak version: 23.0.5

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that `KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction` should include all the manipulation actions (even extractions from the session), and then it works.
Example:

```
KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(session.getKeycloakSessionFactory(), s -> {
    RealmModel realm = session.realms().getRealm(event.getRealmId());
    UserModel u = s.users().getUserById(realm, event.getUserId());
    u.setSingleAttribute(KEY, "value");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the followin works to set an Attribute

```
public MyEventListenerProvider(KeycloakSession keycloakSession) {
        this.keycloakSession = keycloakSession;
    }


    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        log.info(String.format("KeycloakUserEvent:%s:%s", event.getType(), event.getClientId()));
        String userId = event.getUserId();
        EventType eventType = event.getType();
        if (userId != null) {
            RealmModel realm = keycloakSession.realms().getRealm(event.getRealmId());
            UserModel user = keycloakSession.users().getUserById(realm, userId);
            if (user != null) {
                switch (eventType) {
                    ....
                    case LOGIN:
                        try {
                            setUserTimeStamp(user, "lastLoginTimestamp");
                            handled = true;
                        } catch (DateTimeException ex) {
                            log.error("setUserTimeStamp: ", ex);
                        }
                        break;
                }
        }
    }
    
    
    private void setUserTimeStamp(UserModel user, String timestampName) {
        user.setSingleAttribute(timestampName,  ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT));
    }
```